# Node.js JSON data in html is not showing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, mongoose

My Node gets data from Mongoose and sends to webpage. 
but instead of showing real data it display {object: object object: object object: object ...}.
I'm new with node so I don't understand if data is already parsed because jQuery.parseJSON() gives an error(I searched and concluded that data is parsed already). Then why is it showing properly?

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://localhost:1337/users",
        method:'GET',
        success: function(userJSON){
            alert(userJSON);
        }
    })
```

Comment: You can't alert an object, use `console.log` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `console.log(JSON.stringify(userJSON));` to see JSON.